# AVPlayerItem canStepBackward/canPlayReverse Conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayeritem

I'm trying to scrub through a video frame by frame. For this I found multiple options:

- Encode the video for every frame to be a keyframe
- [avplayer seekToTime:time toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero]
- stepForward/stepBackward

Re-encoding the video is not an option, so I have to stick to the other two. I stumbled upon two different problems:

- Jumping between keyframes
- long loading times but precise

Both problems are a no-go.

In AVPlayerItem I've found `canStepBackward`and `canPlayReverse` but I can't find anywhere the conditions for these methods to return true.

Does anyone know these conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

in .h file

```
AVPlayer *avPlayer;
```

in .m file

```
[avPlayer.currentItem canPlayReverse];

[avPlayer.currentItem canStepBackward];
```

These condition being the BOOL value are already set to 1.0 i.e. they are already true. You just have to provide these values to your AVplayerItem object.

You can also try setting the player rate:

`avPlayer.rate=-1.0;`(for negative playing)

`avplayer.rate=1.0;` (for positive playing)